# Open modal popup form on button click using Button ID in jupiter Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, themes

I am trying to Open a modal popup form on button click using Button ID in jupiter Theme. I think the wrapper might be wrong, but I am not sure what It should be, so I have used the general one , please help - I am new to coding!

My attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
.on("click", "1", function(){
   // if( function_exists( 'ninja_forms_display_form' ) ) 
      ninja_forms_display_form( 1 );
});
```

Comment: You are using `.on` and that's fine, but you must use it on something. Here's the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I am afraid It doesn't make a lot of sense to me at the moment, while I am still learning, thanks though! I need a bit more of a hand on this one :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#getintouch').click( function(){
         alert('test');
        // if( function_exists( 'ninja_forms_display_form' ) ) 
        ninja_forms_display_form( 1 );
      });
    });
```

and then still not luck then comment

```
//ninja_forms_display_form( 1 );
```

and then try